# How to receive MMS messages with BroadcastReceiver on M

Tags: java, android, mms

I am working on a new texting app and have gotten to receiving MMS. I understand the proper Broadcast receiver and intent filter to have. The only issue is that given the complete lack of api or guidance on MMS, I am unsure on how to simply receive the MMS and add it to the content provider.

I have searched Google and found some examples but they are either outdated or don't make sense.

***It would be amazing if y'all could provide a reliable example or even give the steps necessary to receive MMS.***

Comment: I assume you know that you have to be the default messaging app to do that, yeah?

Comment: @MikeM. yes of course

Comment: Welp, [here ya go](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/+/master). :-) Seriously, though, it's a pretty huge task. Well beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow post to fully flesh out. I'm sure a lot of users' recommendations would be to use a library, and I know that many of the open source messaging apps do just that, rather than tackle it themselves. I've been meaning to dive into it for a while now, but it's no mean feat. Really, that link should at least give you an idea of what you're in for. Do note that that's a complete messaging client; not just MMS.

Comment: @MikeM.Wow that certainly is a lot. Do you have any MMS receiving specific libraries which would work for me?

Comment: [This one](https://github.com/klinker41/android-smsmms) is really the only one I know of, and that's just because I've seen it mentioned here several times. I've never used it, so I can't vouch for it, but it seems to work just fine for others.

Comment: Oh, ya know what? I just decided to finally have a look at that repo, and it seems that it's only for sending. My bad. I guess I don't know of any for receiving.

Comment: @Mike M. I think I'm just gonna use the android source you linked. Already started and doesn't seem too bad.

Comment: @MikeM. how much of the TransactionService from the Google Code is necessary? It is a lot and I feel like a lot of them are extra things which is not needed to receive MMS. Thanks, Nick

Comment: Yeesh, I'm not sure. From just a quick glance, most of it looks pretty necessary. I'd have to take a closer look, but really, I'm not sure if you'd be able to trim very much; just the few cases that aren't at all applicable to receipt. I might have time later to do a closer inspection. I'll let ya know, if so.

Comment: @MikeM. This thing is just ridiculous, trying to copy it but half of the stuff is deprecated and some of it can't even be imported anymore. There has to be some other way that the apps are working with their MMS. Maybe I will try to find an open source texting app and see what they are doing.

Comment: @MikeM. Tried that and even had problems, maybe I will just ask around and see if I can get a dev to help.

Comment: Yeah, I had a suspicion that it's not going to be as simple as copying that AOSP source. There's always catches when trying to pull something that big. Anyhoo, if you're still interested at all, I know of the [QKSMS project](https://github.com/moezbhatti/qksms). I briefly chatted with the main dev when they dropped and announced it on reddit. I'm not sure which library they use - or if they even still do use a library - but I know that's the route they went when starting out. Might be worth a look, if you've not given up completely yet. :-)